# SOQL accessing a custom field on another table through a join

Tags: soql

On my Contract Object manager I have a customer field called 'Related Site'. This object is found on the Site Object. I am trying to access this by SOQL using a select on Contract. Issue is currently I'm getting the Id of the Site. How do I actually get the custom field directly by using a join?

```
SELECT Contract.Related_Site__c from Contract
```

[image]

From my Related Site I would also like to access a field Site__c (all from Contract).

[image]

Comment: Do you want to access some field on Site object from Contract object query?

Comment: Yes, My example has been simplified. Most of my fields I'm using are from Contract and that's why I'm using that instead of Site.

Comment: Did you try using `select Related_Site__r.name from Contract` which give the name field of Site object related to Contract

Comment: Thank you that worked! So using '__r' will give me the object? what is the difference between using __c and __r?

Comment: __c is the actual field. __r is the relationship that corresponds to that field.

Comment: Is the Related Site object API name is Site__c?

Comment: There is  'Field Label' Lead Site Name with the 'Field Name' Name

Answer (score 1):

__r represents Custom relationship reference. If you want to just the custom field(Look up field) you can use Related_Site__c.

But if you need any data from the parent object while quering Parent object you have to use it as below.

```
Select id,name , Related_Site__r.name from Contract
```

If you are quering Parent object and need child object data in it you can query it as below.

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contract__r) FROM Site__c
```

Comment: When I use __r, do I have access to that whole reference? I can access other fields other than name?

Comment: I have a custom field .Site__c and can't access that by using Related_Site__r.Site__c

Comment: Hi, Do you have Site__c field on Site__c object?

Comment: Yes, I have that in my Related Sites object:
Field LabelSorted, Sort Field Name, Sort Data Type
Site, Site__c, Lookup(Site)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post any screenshot of the field name in contract object and which field you want from Related_Site__r